# using the managed debugging API from C++

Tags: .net, c++, debugging

I'm trying to use the Managed Debugging API from a native C++ program.

I read that it's composed from COM components so I need to use the `CoCreateInstance` method.

I did that but I get the `ERROR_NOT_FOUND` system error which I guess is telling me that it's not registered.

The problem is that I can't find a `corDebug` DLL or anything else I think is related...
Which DLLs do I need to register?

(also I'd expect it to be registered when the framework is installed. weird, isn't it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also check http://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/writing-a-net-debugger-part-1-starting-the-debugging-session/ to find an example of usage for those interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it.
From framework 2 we don't need to register the com components but do it this way:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/01/15/353717.aspx

szEverettVersion holds the version of the installed framework (i think). i.e. "v4.0.30319".